# Video does not work in phone

Tags: html, aframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>360 Video</title>
<meta name="description" content="360 Video — A-Frame">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <video id="video" autoplay="true" src="textures/videoplayback.mp4" loop webkit-playsinline></video>
  </a-assets>
   <a-entity camera position="2 0 3" look-controls wasd-controls>
  <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 1000"
            position="0 0 -1"
            geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03"
            material="color: black; shader: flat">
    <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
                 fill="backwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1"></a-animation>
    <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale"
                 fill="forwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1"></a-animation>
  </a-entity>
</a-entity>
  <a-video src="#video" rotation="0 180 0" width="15" height="7" position="0 0 -10"></a-video>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. I want play video on phone in VR dispaly. But it does not work. It works on laptop but it's not working on phone. What's the issue? How can overcome this problem?
[image]

This is screenshot. It does not play.

Answer (score 0):

For video to play on the phone, you need a user gesture to trigger the play. Even then it's still not the most reliable, but fwiw here's what appears to work (tested on Chrome on Pixel 1):

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-video-tag-click-play

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var scene = document.querySelector("a-scene");
    var vid = document.getElementById("video");
    var videoEl = document.getElementById("vidEl");

    if (scene.hasLoaded) {
      run();
    } else {
      scene.addEventListener("loaded", run);
    }

    function run () {
      if(AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile()) {
        document.querySelector('#splash').style.display = 'flex';
        document.querySelector('#splash').addEventListener('click', function () {
          playVideo();
          this.style.display = 'none';
        })
      } else {
          playVideo();
      }
    }

    function playVideo () {
      vid.play();
      if(AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile()) {
         videoEl.components.material.material.map.image.play(); 
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace your video link code with this line:

```
<video id="video" autoplay="true" src="textures/videoplayback.mp4" loop webkit-playsinline playsinline></video>
```

.. and make sure your 'src' path is correct.

Comment: No, it does not work. The video does not play on phone.